# Unable to build after upgrading reactjs Unknown version 4 of samsung node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js$0

Tags: reactjs

I have updated my react js app ( react + redux +react-router) and when i tried to build it i am seeing a strange error.

```
    ./src/index.js
BrowserslistError: [BABEL] /home/sateesh/apps/react-app/src/index.js: Unknown version 4 of samsung (While processing: "/home/sateesh/apps/react-app/node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/index.js$0")
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

And here i my index.js which is created as part of create-react-app

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';



ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint. 
reportWebVitals();
```

And i don't see any reference to 'samsung' in babel-preset-react-app index.js !! Here is the code of index.js of that dependency.

```
'use strict';

const create = require('./create');

module.exports = function (api, opts) {
  // This is similar to how `env` works in Babel:
  // We are not using `env` because it’s ignored in versions > babel-core@6.10.4:
  // It’s also nice that we can enforce `NODE_ENV` being specified.
  const env = process.env.BABEL_ENV || process.env.NODE_ENV;
  return create(api, opts, env);
};
```

And finally here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "react-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "rc-tooltip": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.9.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.7",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reqwest": "^2.0.5",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build:local": "REACT_APP_ENV=local react-scripts build",
    "build:dev": "REACT_APP_ENV=dev react-scripts build",
    "build:test": "REACT_APP_ENV=test react-scripts build",
    "build:prod": "REACT_APP_ENV=prod react-scripts build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks
Sateesh

Comment: Have you tried rolling back the package version changes to a working state, then update one at a time to see where it breaks?